# Docusign have Transform PDF fields feature

Tags: java, docusignapi

Docusign have Transform PDF fields feature, I want to implement this API feature for two signers: Primary Signer and secondary signer.
I have given the name of Form fields accordingly PrimarySignereSignSignHere and SecondarySignereSignSignHere. But both signing fields for primary and secondary is available to sign for primary signer.

Please guide me how to differentiate(assign) in signing fields for Primary and secondary signer.

Is there any feature in docusign through which the counter signer signing can be done by API methods silently without using UI or email.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes it's possible, but it's not the easiest thing to accomplish. By default formFields are automatically transferred to Recipient 1 when the transformpdfformfields flag is set to 'true', which makes assigning to multiple signers problematic.

The way to go about doing this would be through composite templates. First off, with both of these recipients you'll want a unique role or a prefix attached to it. Say for example you had Signer as a role and CoSigner as a role. First you would declare both of these as recipients with some form of tab attached, then you would pick a prefix for the fields on the PDF side IE: Sign1 or CoSign and attach them as the label for each tab you want to goto that role. Once the formfields transform, they'll automatically be assigned to the first recipient.

After that you can make a GET call to retrieve a list of the fields that were created, checking for the prefix you assigned. Since Signer was my first role, everything would be under Signer. I would then do a GET to my recipientId/tabs, pull a list of everything with the CoSign prefix, then make another call to update the owner of just those tabs to the CoSigner role.

It takes an extra call or two, but you can absolutely do it.

Regards,

Matt

Comment: Hi Ritu, I'll need some additional detail in order to see what's going on. Can you open a support case at https://support.docusign.com? We'll want to have a closer look at your API logs and would strongly discourage against posting them here. You can either reply here with your case number or send me an email and I'll make sure it's picked up -- matt.king@docusign.com